# How to Edit php.ini ( php version 7.1) file on amazon AMI instance

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, instance, amazon-ami

I want to change my default php.ini file configuration on amazon-ec2 AMI instance.i can access any my instance using putty and filezila.

Comment: You mean "I cant" or "I can"?

Comment: yes i can edit and below is the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This is only for php version 7.1 or greater.**

1. Conncet your instance using filezila or winSCp .
2. Navigate to **/etc** folder.
3. you can see .ini file at bottom name **php-7.1.ini**.
4. using filezila right click on that file and click **File Permissions.**
5. If your file permission is **777** then good to go or it is any other than 777 then change it permission using command line interface just remember it's current permission.
6. use this command to change permission **sudo chmod 777  /etc/php-7.1.ini**
7. Now you can edit your .ini file.
8. After edit your file set back to it's previous permission to **644 or whatever your default ini permission**  using this command **sudo chmod 644  /etc/php-7.1.ini**.
9. And it's done dont forgot to restart server using this command **sudo service httpd restart**.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it with 3 easy steps.
No need to change any file permissions.

1. Locate the php.ini file (mostly on `/etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini`)
2. Edit and Save it properly on Ubuntu File Editors.
3. Restart the Apache Server.
   `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Everything works perfectly.
For more detailed steps please [look at here.](https://8subjects.com/3-easy-steps-to-change-php-configuration-in-aws-ec2-ubuntu-server-php-ini-ec2/)